# Android configuration profiles

Tags: android, configuration-files, properties-file

I am working on new Android application and came to the point where I need different configuration profiles, which are loaded once the Application is started.
I use properties files in /assets folder, but I don't know how I can tell the Android process which one to use.

Is there any possibility how to pass some "command-line" argument to process when it's started? Or how can I choose between multiple configurations when starting the app?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this the same as the Android OS confiuration profile?

Comment: I don't think so. What do you mean by that?